# Does a plugin with a AJAX button filter exist?

Tags: filters, ajax

I would like to add something like this (see picture) to a website, with this functionality ( https://www.capitalone.com/applications/alexa/ )

[image]

Is there a plugin that can do this?

Comment: Note that the page you linked to does not use AJAX for that, that's some sort of tabbed interface, or masonry/isotope implementation. Your problem is a frontend/JS/HTML problem at the moment, not WP specific. Either way, plugin recommendations are off topic here